# Fullcalendar CalEvent for single day end date will be null

Tags: c#, javascript

```
calEvent.end.getFullYear() + "/" + (calEvent.end.getMonth()+1) + "/" + calEvent.end.getDate()
```

when i hover mouse to see the `enddate is = null`,
but for the range for few day is ok and the end date result will show,
how to fix for the single day?

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar has one issue that if start date and end date are same it simply makes end date as null.

If the event's end date is the same as the start date, FullCalendar considers it to be 1-day in duration (with a blank assumed end time), so it is one-in-the-same. It prefers to store less data than more. So carefully check if start date and end date are coming same.

But you could simply do this as a workaround:
     function(event) {
            var start = event.start;
            var end = event.end || start;
        }

Check following link.

https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1014